# Single pie chart out of set won't render QGIS

Tags: chart, qgis-2.18

I've joined a CSV with a shapefile to demonstrate boardings/alightings at specific transit stops, and was able to successfully generate a pie chart for all but one of the points via the Diagrams tool. I haven't found another question similar to this one on the forums. Any ideas would be helpful. I've included an image of the map.

[image: Singular pie chart that doesn't fill]